# Can I use "presentor mode" on my Windows Phone 7 like Joe Belfiore to give app demos?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I would like to be able to show whats happening on my phone, on a computer screen or projector.

This seems like it must be possible since Microsoft does it in all of their demos, but I can't seem to figure out how.

For example, I've build an app, and I want to demo it to a room of prospective clients.  I can't really use the emulator very well during a presentation.  I'd like the room to be able to see what I'm doing on a big screen instead of all huddling around my phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've asked various people at Microsoft about this and, unfortunately, the response I always get is that Microsoft is not able to load to load the necessary "VGA Patch" externally.

Unless you can do your demo in the emulator, cameras are the only way to go at this point.

Comment: This is correct, phones you see do that are running an MS internal only build.  It's a cool feature and I would love it to be generally available, but you can imagine the DRM implications that make that impossible.

Comment: Can't it be done using TeamViewer or Skype screen share feature. I had tried in Android but is it available for Windows Phone 8 as well ?

Answer (score 0):

What you've seen was done with internal hardware. Perhaps you could approach Microsoft to see if they are willing to assist in any way.

Comment: I agree, if you are a Microsoft Partner ask your rep for help.

Comment: Read here: http://charlespetzold.com/blog/2010/10/Windows-Phone-7-and-the-Art-of-Presentation.html  In many MS demos they also use a camera pointed to the screen, but I suppose it's not very practical/economic (but maybe with a good webcam could be doable?)

Comment: I'd be of the view that the more people ask, the better the chances are that someone internally goes, hey why don't we do X to help these people out with what we're using.

Comment: I've seen this used too, would also be useful especially for capturing video of apps that depend on Hub integration etc without point a camera at a phone.