# Tool to send screen from Windows Phone 7 to PC

Tags: windows-phone-7

what is the tool used to project the screen from the phone to the PC?

I've seen it being used in a presentation but can't find it anywhere.

Thanks!

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200847/can-i-use-presentor-mode-on-my-windows-phone-7-like-joe-belfiore-to-give-app-de

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an internal tool used by Microsoft staff only at the moment.

Camera / projector is another option.

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve it by using for instance the following tools and after connecting a projector to your pc ofc:

1. http://www.mymobiler.com/
2. [ActiveSync Remote Display (Microsoft Mobile Dev. Powertoys)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=74473fd6-1dcc-47aa-ab28-6a2b006edfe9#Overview)

Comment: I believe neither of those support Windows Phone 7

Comment: Humm...i was hoping win mobile 7 would be more backward compatible :(