# how to show mirror view of windows phone on pc for app presentation?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, xna, nokia, windows-phone-7-emulator

We are a group of students who are finishing up developing our windows phone xna game and its our first time using the windows phone. We have a Lumia 610 for testing and we were wondering if there was a way to mirror what is seen on the phone onto a pc so that it can be sent to a projector since our game will use multiple touch areas and the accelerometer which is hard to present with only a mouse pointer.

Alternative two - is there a way to connect the phone to a projector, maybe hdmi, dvi or vga output from the usb?

Comment: There's an 'official' way to output the video through the USB port, that Microsoft uses for its conferences. Unfortunately, it is not open for third parties. I don't believe there's any way to do what you're asking with a 'normal' phone, but maybe some homebrew apps are able to provide the same features to an unlocked phone.

Comment: yes, i have seen some homebrew apps but would rather not have to go that route.

Comment: Then the answer is quite straightforward: you can't ;)

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261757/tool-to-send-screen-from-windows-phone-7-to-pc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really seems to be no way of doing this without a homebrew app, and most of these dont seem to be that good.

How did we solve this issue for our presentation?

Well my answer to this question and a tip for anyone else in this situation is to simply use the camera on your laptop or a webcam. Then tilt the screen down and hold the phone in front of the camera, this will show everyone what you the player sees if you hook up the laptop to the projector. Simple solution but not something you might consider right away, it worked well for us.