# Writing a Tool to Stream Windows Phone to a Projector or Screen

Tags: windows-phone-7, streaming, usb, projector

There are several posts about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200847/can-i-use-presentor-mode-on-my-windows-phone-7-like-joe-belfiore-to-give-app-d), [here](https://superuser.com/questions/219019/windows-phone-7-how-to-display-on-projector) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261757/tool-to-send-screen-from-windows-phone-7-to-pc).

I understand that Microsoft has their own tool, what would be involved in writing one? Or would it be something specific to the hardware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. MS uses a patched version of the operating system that supports VGA output, so there's no signal to obtain from the USB port.